# Can PDF documents contain "unreachable" content?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I am investigating Java PDF libraries.

I have a tried

`org.apache.pdfbox`

```
File file = new File("file.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);

// Instantiate PDFTextStripper class
PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();

// Retrieving text from PDF document
String text = pdfStripper.getText(document);
System.out.println(text);

// Closing the document
document.close();
```

`com.itextpdf.text.pdf`

```
public static final String SRC = "file.pdf";
public static final String DEST = "streams";

public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(DEST);
    new BruteForce().parse(SRC, DEST);
}

public void parse(final String src, final String dest) throws IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfObject obj;
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getXrefSize(); i++) {
        obj = reader.getPdfObject(i);

        if ((obj != null) && obj.isStream()) {
            PRStream stream = (PRStream) obj;
            byte[] b;
            try {
                b = PdfReader.getStreamBytes(stream);
            } catch (UnsupportedPdfException e) {
                b = PdfReader.getStreamBytesRaw(stream);
            }
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(String.format(dest, i));
            fos.write(b);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } else {
            final PdfDictionary pdfDictionary = (PdfDictionary) obj;

            System.out.println("\t>>>>> " + pdfDictionary + "\t\t" + pdfDictionary.getKeys());

            final Set<PdfName> pdfNames = pdfDictionary.getKeys();

            for (final PdfName pdfName : pdfNames) {
                final PdfObject pdfObject = pdfDictionary.get(pdfName);
                final int type = pdfObject.type();
                switch (type) {
                case PdfObject.NULL:
                    System.out.println("\t NULL " + pdfObject);
                    break;
                case PdfObject.BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println("\t BOOLEAN " + pdfObject);
                    break;
                case PdfObject.NUMBER:
                    System.out.println("\t NUMBER " + pdfObject);
                    break;
                case PdfObject.STRING:
                    System.out.println("\t STRING " + pdfObject);
                    break;
                case PdfObject.NAME:
                    System.out.println("\t NAME " + pdfObject);
                    break;
                case PdfObject.ARRAY:
                    System.out.println("\t ARRAY " + pdfObject);
                    break;
                case PdfObject.DICTIONARY:
                    System.out.println("\t DICTIONARY " + ((PdfDictionary)pdfObject).getKeys());
                    break;
                case PdfObject.STREAM:
                    System.out.println("\t STREAM " + pdfObject);
                    break;
                case PdfObject.INDIRECT:
                    System.out.println("\t INDIRECT " +pdfObject.getIndRef());
                    break;
                default:

                }
                System.out.println("\t\t--- " + pdfObject.type());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`com.snowtide.pdf`

String pdfFilePath = "file.pdf";

```
    Document pdf = PDF.open(pdfFilePath);

    final List<Annotation> annotations = pdf.getAllAnnotations();
    for (final Annotation annotation : annotations) {
        System.out.println(annotation.pageNumber());
    }

    System.out.println(pdf.getAttributeMap());
    System.out.println(pdf.getAttributeKeys());
    System.out.println("=============================");

    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(1024);
    pdf.pipe(new OutputTarget(text));
    pdf.close();
    System.out.println(text);
```

I can extract all visible PDF content including links, text, and images apart from what appears to be a "Watermark" that appears on every page.

Can PDF documents contain "unreachable" content?

Is there no way to extract **ALL** content from a PDF file?

UPDATE

thinking the "watermark" was an image I tried this code

```
File fileW = new File("file.pdf");
PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(fileW);
PDPageTree list = document.getPages();
for (PDPage page : list) {
    PDResources pdResources = page.getResources();
    for (COSName c : pdResources.getXObjectNames()) {

        System.out.println("????? ::>>>" + c);

        PDXObject o = pdResources.getXObject(c);
        if (o instanceof org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject) {
            File file = new File("Temp/" + System.nanoTime() + ".png");
            ImageIO.write(((org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.graphics.image.PDImageXObject) o).getImage(), "png", file);
        } else {

        }
    }
}
```

The PDF does contain images of the authors, however the "watermark" is not reached with this approach.

Comment: Maybe the watermark is an image. You see text, but there are no characters, only pixels. Maybe the watermark is drawn without using a font; that is: the shapes of the glyphs are drawn using PDF syntax. You'd be able to extract a stream of path construction and path painting operations, but if you don't know PDF syntax, you won't understand it. Maybe the watermark is added as an annotation, and maybe you only looked at the page content forgetting the annotations. Since I can give you three guesses (there could be more reasons), I think your question is too broad and should be closed.

Comment: I suggest you look at the PDF with PDFDebugger or RUPS to see what it is made of. There is more in a PDF than the objects you mention. For example, streams can contain operators and their parameters.

Comment: No, the wartermark doesn't have to be an image. It could be a text or a vector graphic.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, PDFDebugger doesnt show the "watermark". I tried extracting streams via iTEXT and that approach didnt work either.

Comment: Then it would be nice to share the PDF for an investigation whether this is a bug.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr the associated doi is 10.1002/elps.201400544.

Comment: And what should I do with this "doi"?

Comment: Sorry, I live in a doi world (and assumed everyone else did) google (or Crossref) will find a document from a doi. The search gives this link https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/elps.201400544 however the pdf is only available for "account holders". I cannot share this pdf

Comment: I assume the watermark simply is better hidden than the OP looked. And I am sure you can find it using RUPS or PDFDebugger. Unfortunately the OP does not share a PDF, so this is hard to illustrate.

Comment: @mkl link added please illustrate how I programatically extract the Accepted Article text visible on all but the first page of the linked pdf

Comment: "The Accepted Article text" is not drawn as text. Instead *the shapes of the glyphs are drawn using PDF syntax* as @Bruno already conjectured, i.e. they are a blob of MoveTo, LineTo, CurveTo, and Fill instruction in the page content stream, easy to find with either RUPS or PDFDebugger. I can write up some details when I'm back from the vet collecting one of our dogs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page content streams of the example document provided by the OP have the following structure from page 2 onward:

1. A textual header line "www.electrophoresis-journal.com Page X Electrophoresis":

   ```
   BT
   /F1 9.12 Tf
   1 0 0 1 72.024 798.46 Tm
   /GS7 gs
   0 g
   0 G
   [(w)11(w)11(w)11(.)-12(e)-2(l)15(e)-2(c)23(t)-10(r)-8(o)26(pho)26(r)-8(e)-2(s)21(i)-10(s)] TJ
   ET
   [...]
   BT
   1 0 0 1 441.53 798.46 Tm
   [(E)6(l)-10(e)-2(c)23(t)-10(r)-8(o)26(pho)26(r)-8(e)23(s)-5(i)15(s)] TJ
   ET
   BT
   1 0 0 1 497.47 798.46 Tm
   [( )] TJ
   ET
   BT
   1 0 0 1 72.024 787.9 Tm
   [( )] TJ
   ET
   ```

   This text can easily be extracted using normal iText or PDFBox text extraction.
2. A textual multi-line footer "Received: ... All rights reserved."

   ```
   BT
   1 0 0 1 72.024 109.7 Tm
   [(R)9(e)-2(c)23(e)-2(i)-10(v)26(e)-2(d:)41( )] TJ
   ET
   [...]
   BT
   1 0 0 1 72.024 47.76 Tm
   [(T)6(hi)-10(s)21( )-12(a)23(r)-8(t)15(i)-10(c)23(l)-10(e)23( )13(i)-10(s)21( )-12(pr)-8(o)26(t)15(e)-2(c)23(t)-10(e)-2(d)26( )-12(by)53( )-12(c)-2(o)26(p)-25(y)53(r)-8(i)-10(g)26(ht)-10(.)-12( )-12(A)38(l)-10(l)15( )13(r)-8(i)-10(g)26(ht)15(s)-5( )13(r)-8(e)23(s)-5(e)-2(r)-8(v)26(e)-2(d)26(.)] TJ
   ET
   BT
   1 0 0 1 278.52 47.76 Tm
   [( )] TJ
   ET
   BT
   1 0 0 1 72.024 37.2 Tm
   [( )] TJ
   ET
   ```

   This text also can easily be extracted using normal iText or PDFBox text extraction.
3. A set of PDF path creation and filling operations using a custom graphics state forming the transparent "Accepted Article" writing on the left of the page:

   ```
   /GS8 gs
   0 g
   39.605 266.51 m
   39.605 261.29 39.605 256.06 39.605 250.84 c
   42.197 249.94 44.776 248.99 47.367 248.09 c
   49.296 247.41 50.704 247.08 51.649 247.08 c
   52.413 247.08 53.058 247.38 53.609 247.97 c
   54.191 248.54 54.548 249.82 54.729 251.77 c
   55.18 251.77 55.624 251.77 56.075 251.77 c
   56.075 247.51 56.075 243.26 56.075 239.02 c
   55.624 239.02 55.18 239.02 54.729 239.02 c
   54.36 240.72 53.903 241.8 53.314 242.3 c
   52.144 243.3 49.809 244.47 46.247 245.67 c
   32.719 250.33 19.286 255.25 5.7645 259.91 c
   5.7645 260.26 5.7645 260.61 5.7645 260.95 c
   19.43 265.57 33.014 270.43 46.679 275.05 c
   49.984 276.16 52.075 277.24 53.064 278.15 c
   54.053 279.06 54.623 280.36 54.729 282 c
   55.18 282 55.624 282 56.075 282 c
   56.075 276.68 56.075 271.35 56.075 266.03 c
   55.624 266.03 55.18 266.03 54.729 266.03 c
   54.623 267.64 54.303 268.75 53.753 269.31 c
   53.202 269.88 52.519 270.15 51.718 270.15 c
   50.666 270.15 48.97 269.75 46.679 268.95 c
   44.319 268.15 41.971 267.31 39.605 266.51 c
   h
   36.92 265.67 m
   30.284 263.43 23.686 261.05 17.045 258.81 c
   23.686 256.5 30.284 254.07 36.92 251.77 c
   36.92 256.4 36.92 261.04 36.92 265.67 c
   h
   f*
   [...]
   35.361 630.34 m
   40.294 630.31 44.156 631.32 46.967 633.29 c
   49.784 635.27 51.18 637.63 51.18 640.31 c
   51.18 642.1 50.573 643.67 49.364 645 c
   48.156 646.3 46.141 647.43 43.236 648.31 c
   43.48 648.62 43.712 648.93 43.962 649.24 c
   47.261 648.83 50.253 647.57 52.989 645.6 c
   55.731 643.62 57.089 641.06 57.089 638.05 c
   57.089 634.76 55.549 631.92 52.413 629.63 c
   49.302 627.3 45.158 626.1 39.899 626.1 c
   34.203 626.1 29.802 627.33 26.585 629.71 c
   23.405 632.07 21.834 635.12 21.834 638.73 c
   21.834 641.8 23.048 644.34 25.496 646.28 c
   27.981 648.22 31.267 649.24 35.361 649.24 c
   35.361 642.94 35.361 636.64 35.361 630.34 c
   h
   33.258 630.34 m
   33.258 634.56 33.258 638.78 33.258 643 c
   31.117 642.91 29.633 642.7 28.763 642.37 c
   27.417 641.87 26.341 641.14 25.571 640.16 c
   24.801 639.19 24.406 638.13 24.406 637.06 c
   24.406 635.42 25.158 633.91 26.729 632.64 c
   28.306 631.34 30.466 630.55 33.258 630.34 c
   h
   f*
   ```

   (The instructions I quoted draw the initial 'A' and the final 'e'.)

   This writing cannot be extracted using normal iText or PDFBox text extraction as it neither is drawn using text instruction nor is marked with an **ActualText** entry. (The latter could be recognized using customized iText or PDFBox text extraction.)

   But you can extract this writing as the sequence of path creation and drawing commands it consists of using an implementation of the iText `ExtRenderListener` interface or a subclass of the PDFBox `PDFGraphicsStreamEngine`.
4. The actual text content of the article, opaque, using text drawing instructions, e.g.

   ```
   BT
   /F2 10.08 Tf
   1 0 0 1 72.024 760.78 Tm
   /GS7 gs
   0 g
   [(H)-7(I)8(G)16(H)-7( )-106(TH)-6(R)32(O)-7(U)8(G)16(H)-7(P)16(U)8(T )-106(M)-7(U)8(LTI)] TJ
   ET
   BT
   1 0 0 1 212.98 760.78 Tm
   [(-)] TJ
   ET
   BT
   1 0 0 1 216.1 760.78 Tm
   [(O)-7(R)8(G)-7(A)8(N)32( )-130(M)15(ETA)32(BO)-6(LO)16(M)-7(I)8(C)8(S)8( )-130(I)8(N)8( )-106(TH)-6(E)24( )-130(A)8(P)16(P)16(/)-7(P)16(S)8(1 )-106(M)-7(O)-7(U)8(S)8(E)24( )-130(M)15(O)-7(D)8(EL)24( )-106(O)-7(F)16( )] TJ
   ET
   ```

   This text also can easily be extracted using normal iText or PDFBox text extraction.

Concerning the OP's questions, therefore,

> I can extract all visible PDF content including links, text, and images apart from what appears to be a "Watermark" that appears on every page.
>
> Can PDF documents contain "unreachable" content?

That content is not "unreachable", it merely is not text drawn using text drawing instructions but instead text drawn like an arbitrary shape.

> Is there no way to extract ALL content from a PDF file?

You can extract that content, merely not as text but instead as a collection of path creation and drawing instructions. Whenever you suspect such instructions to actually draw letter shapes, you can try to determine the text by rendering these paths as a bitmap and applying OCR.